# Firebase Console Recurring Cloud Messaging notification does not work

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the FCM in my android native app and it works perfectly with instant and scheduled notifications.

However, when I create a recurring notification in FCM console, the notification does not receive.

[image]

[image]

I have used these libraries in the app and I'm not using the custom firebase messaging class for messaging (I used the SDK Firebase Messaging class to receive messages)

```
    //firebase
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```

**Could someone help me with this?**

Comment: It would be useful if you could provide the code you used to implement FCM in your app. And which parameters you're using to create the notification in the console

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I have used these libraries in the app and I'm not using the custom firebase messaging class for messaging (I used the SDK Firebase Messaging class to receive messages)

    //firebase
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'

Comment: I would suggest creating the custom `FirebaseMessagingService` as described in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages)

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes but I'm using it without a custom class for many years for campaigns I will try this custom class but I didn't find anything  in their doc that mention you must use this class